# Is coding MASM for linux illegal?

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, masm

Almost 30 years after MASM 6.0, It is still being used for educational purposes worldwide.
The 16 bit MASM is what is being taught.

I use linux and am quite pained that not a single MASM assembler is available.

```
1.Wine does not work
2.DOSBOX does not run the linker
3.I don't have an windows XP cd to run in a VM
4.My only windows computer is windows 8.1, which does not support MASM
```

People suggest NASM but the syntax is not same as a 16 bit MASM assembler.

Is it illegal to make a MASM for linux, or any windows 7 and above??

I was thinking about coding a simple one for educational purposes myself.

Comment: For a quick solution: *why* don't you use NASM instead? The developers maintain a [list of differences](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2), which don't seem to be that critical.

Comment: It is definitely not illegal. But your gripes with other assembler seem to be of syntactic nature - instead of coding an assembler, consider to make a preprocessor which massages source code a bit, so that source compatible with another assembler rolls out.

Comment: @Rhymoid Its a painful process to switch between the syntaxes. And I use it for educational purpose only, not powerful code generation.That is why I specifically looked for an exact one to MASM 6.0.

Comment: @Bushmills I was thinking of a program that takes in MASM code, and prints out a C program which can be run.  A little digging in SO, showed some EULA copyright issues which makes me scared about microsoft.

Comment: an ASM to C translator isn't trivial. More, some constructs which you can easily code in assembly, are difficult to impossible to represent as C code

Comment: Not to mention that if you're writing DOS code (I don't see why else you'd be using MASM 6.0), you're bound to be using a bunch of interrupts that won't work in Linux. Plus the memory model is different.

Comment: The real question is the MASM syntax legally protected by microsoft.  Microsoft may not care even if it is but that is secondary.  If nasm supports masm syntax then that almost answers the question, and/or the nasm folks have to deal with it.  Nothing prevents you from trying, the better solution is to teach your students using nasm instead of masn, or if you are not a teacher then the education here is learning to migrate from one tool to the next.  It isnt just masm but a high percentage of stuff taught in general is not real world.

Comment: if you have the ability and ambition to make a masm compatible parser then you certainly have the skills to learn the nasm syntax and just use nasm.  Or even better learn to write code that has minimal dependencies on the toolchain so that porting is much easier.

Comment: See for example [jwasm](http://www.japheth.de/JWasm.html) which is _a free MASM-compatible assembler_.

Comment: If your main syntactic complaint is the argument ordering (e.g. `mov dest, src` instead of `mov src, dest`), note that many assemblers have options to accept either. If it's all the non-instruction and pseudo-instruction stuff added by MASM (macros, synthetic instructions, etc.), most have similar capabilities, although they look different. If learning the new syntax is just not an option, then see Jesters suggestion for jwasm - there are a couple other free assemblers that approximate MASM compatibility as well - Google can help you there..

Comment: I doubt it's a legality issue, since all the DOS assemblers I used (and there were many) used the same basic syntax.  There were differences in directives and macros of course.

Comment: The Microsoft version of Masm 6.0 and later is ML.EXE. It's a 32 bit app using a dos extender if running under 16 bit dos. Otherwise it runs fine in 32 bit dos console windows. The main issue is getting a copy of the old Microsoft tool sets for Visual C / C++ 2.2 or older, (or Visual C / C++ 4.1, which also includes 16 version 1.52) which will run fine in a Windows dos console window, using a batch file to setup environment variables before using the tool set.

Comment: It seems like it would be a lot easier to get your hands on a Windows XP CD to run in a VM, than it would be to code an assembler.

Comment: Have you tried FreeDOS (in a VM)?